# Rather mysterious SocketException with Java 1.6 on CentOS 4

Tags: java, networking

I have a JUnit test of a JAX-RS web service. The test launches embedded tomcat, and then talks to it via the Apache CXF JAX-RS client.

Consider this backtrace:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.getOption(PlainSocketImpl.java:286)
        at java.net.Socket.getSoTimeout(Socket.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.available(HttpClient.java:356)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:273)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:310)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:987)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:923)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
```

This fails *only* on CentOS 4.8. The same unit test (which launches an embedded tomcat and then talks to a web service in it) works just fine on a wide variety of other systems. Note the extreme oddity of this backtrace: `HttpHRLConnection` has called `HttpClient` to get a new connection, and that later class has apparently closed its own socket before the connection has been returned where any code of mine could get to it.

Further, the test has friends that do the same server setup of the same service and talk to it without issues.

Even further, the following incantation (slightly abbreviated) is a workaround:

```
@Before
public void pingServiceToWorkAroundCentos() {
   try {
      /* ... code to make a connection to the service and close it ... */
   } catch (Throwable t) {
      // do nothing
   }
}
```

In other words, if I arrange for an extra throwaway connection before running each of the test cases, that uses up whatever this problem is.

What could this be?

Comment: Have you tried `strace -e network`ing it?

Comment: +1 for using the word "mysterious" rather than "weird" or "strange". "Mysterious" is much more apropos, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only a backtrace and no code here, I am assuming that there is some sort of race condition or bug where the socket is being closed prior by another thread while this current thread is attempting to get the OutputStream.

Looking at the source for the JDK I see this...

```
public Object getOption(int opt) throws SocketException {
    if (isClosedOrPending()) {
        throw new SocketException("Socket Closed");
    }
    ... snip ...
```

the isClosedOrPending method checks whether the internal FD is null or if a close is pending, i.e. close has been called on the socket.

Good luck tracking it down.

Comment: Yes, I read that too. The question is, how did it get closed between when HttpURLConnection opened it and when it tried to get that option?

Comment: Need to see all the code. I am assuming it is closed by some other thread.

Comment: 'All the code' is all of Apache CXF. Not really postable. How could I Java thread possibly get access to the socket in between when HttpURLConnection creates it and when it goes to fetch the option? It's entirely in private fields of the connection code in the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing mysterious about it. You have closed the socket and then continued to use it.

Closing either the input or the output stream of the socket closes the other stream and the socket.

Comment: No, look at the backtrace. This happens inside of HttpURLConnection, where I have no possible way to insert a close between the creation and the usage.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is a JDK bug.

HttpClient was modified in a recent commit:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/diff/e6dc1d9bc70b/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/http/HttpClient.java

The getSoTimeout() call needs to be in a try/catch block, for now unfortunately the only real option is to downgrade the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to an issue we ran into where the httpclient pooled connections were kept alive longer than the corresponding server side connections in tomcat. Basically this results in stale connections in the  httpclient connection pool. When httpclient tries to use these, they basically fail. I believe httpclient actually recovers from this using the standard retry handler.

The solution is to double check your timeout settings client and serverside and your retry policy.